# Why isn't Melpa showing some packages?

Tags: package-repositories

I want to install the following package in spacemacs: https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clj-refactor.el, but when I do this: M-x package-install clj-refactor, I don't see a clj-refactor option in Melpa suggestions. Instead I see a discover-clj-refactor package. Why isn't Melpa showing the cli-refactor package? Do I have to update Melpa or something?

Comment: Maybe you have it already installed... Have you checked?

Comment: Double check that you've updated metadata for latest packages in Melpa. M-x list-packages and wait for it to check for updates.

Answer (score 1):

`clj-refactor` is included with Spacemacs. `package-install` only lists packages that aren't already installed. Try `package-list-packages` to see all packages, installed and uninstalled.